# How to stop the game when the obstacle is hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I am developing an game in unity in that i am able to run the game but when the game hits an obstacle the game doesn't stop.I have used a method to stop the game but it didn't works.

My scripts are

Player.cs

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour{

    // The force which is added when the player jumps
    // This can be changed in the Inspector window
    public Vector2 jumpForce = new Vector2(0, 300);
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody2D;

    void Start()
    {
        this.myRigidbody2D = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("space"))
        {
            this.myRigidbody2D.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            this.myRigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpForce);
        }
        Vector2 screenPosition = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        if (screenPosition.y > Screen.height || screenPosition.y < 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }
    public void Die()
    {   
        if (Input.GetKeyUp ("r")) 
            {
                Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
            }
    }
}
```

Generate.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Generate : MonoBehaviour 
    {
    public GameObject Pencils;
    int score = 0;
    public Player p;

    void Start()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("CreateObstacle", 2.8f, 2.5f);
    }
    void OnGUI () 
    {
        GUI.color = Color.black;
        GUILayout.Label(" Score: " + score.ToString());
    }
    public void CreateObstacle()
    {
        Instantiate(Pencils);
        {
            score++;
        }
        //Player player = Pencils.GetComponent<Player> ();
        //player.Die();

    }
    public void destroy()
    {
        p.Die ();
        //Generate.SetTrigger ("Die");
        //Die = true;
        //public bool isChecked = false;
        //public void Check(Die)
        p mygen=destroy.GetComponent<p>();
        if (mygen)
        {
            if (p.transform.tag == "Die")
                mygen.isChecked = true;
        }//else
        //  is Checked=false;
        {
            CancelInvoke("CreateObstacle");
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't quite find your 'game stopping' code in the listings. If by 'stopping the game' you mean pausing it or stopping the in-game time flow, something like [Time.timeScale](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) should do.

In order to pause the game you could do `Time.timeScale = 0f;` and in order to resume it you just do `Time.timeScale = 1f;`

If you are using Unity's physics engine you might also have to modify [Time.fixedDeltaTime](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) (so that your physics doesn't run while the game is paused).

Comment: I want execute the void destroy() method from the Generate.cs as the Die() method executes from the Player.cs

Comment: I don't get it. Please clarify your question if it is not what you are asking. (Edit the question itself, don't just post comments)

Answer (score 0):

> I want execute the void destroy() method from the Generate.cs as the Die() method executes from the Player.cs

If you want to call destroy() from generate.cs when die() in player.cs is executed you simply need to call destroy() in the die().

You will need to create a gameobject in player.cs that will be an instance of your generate.cs:

```
public gameObject generateInstance;
```

You will then need to call the destroy method of that generateInstance in the die method of your player.cs script:

```
public void Die()
{   
    if (Input.GetKeyUp ("r")) 
        {
            generateInstance.destroy();
            Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevel);
        }
}
```

Dont forget to set the generateInstance to be Generate.cs, either by dragging it onto the Player.cs script in the Unity inspector, or by getting it directly through code.